# How to Route Php Files Using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have three folders--Model, Views and Controller--and I have stored the index.php file in the Views folder. I am not able to route the files. I tried the following code in the .htaccess file

```
RewiteEngine On
RewiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: Where did you locate your .htaccess file? in `view` folder?

Comment: Before you wire this up much further, might be an idea to have your MVC code below/outside the public folder, and just drop in the index.php and your static resources into your publicly available assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your project structure is something like below:

```
Model
Controller
Views -> index.php
```

You can use this `.htaccess` file in the root folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^$ view/ [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) Views/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This sends all the traffic to `Views` folder.

And another this `.htaccess` file inside the `Views` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This sends all the traffic throw `index.php` file with a pretty URL.

**Tips:**

But I suggest changing your structure as below that seems to be better:

```
public -> index.php #will include bootstrap.php
          assets
          .htacess

app --->> Model
          Controller
          View
          Helper
          bootstrap.php #contains autoload and includes
          ...
.htaccess
```

So all traffic will pass throw `public/index.php` and the application folder and services are separate from public and assets.